# Drupal 8, don't automatically execute the view after the first load of the view page

Tags: views, 8

I created a view page from the admin interface. Then when I go to the view page url with my browser, the view is displayed and show automatically some results.

Now, I want force the user to click on the execute view button for display results. I mean, the user go to the view page url, only exposed filters are displayed, he must click on the view submit button for display results of the view.

It's possible to configure that from the view interface configuration (I didn't find..) or I must use a custom module ? (and how?)

Thanks you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find from the view ui how configure for "force" the user to submit the view for show results ! In the view ui, to the right (in the advanced settings), click on "exposed form style" and choose "Input required" :)